# AdDuplex interstital intitialization fails with unspecified error

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, monogame, adduplex

I am developing a game using MonoGame and C# for Windows 10 UWP. I am having a problem when I try to use interstitial ads in the game. I make the initialization call like so in the `App.xaml.cs`:

```
AdDuplex.AdDuplexClient.Initialize("application-id-here");
```

The debugger does not break on the call itself, but rather breaks after the `OnLaunched` event is complete without specifying an exception.

I am using the latest version of the AdDuplex SDK. Tried using both the VS2015 extension and the Nuget package. Same result. I know it is not MonoGame, because I tried a similar call in a normal XAML app and got exactly the same result.

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: Where did you put the AdDuplex Ad control? try not to put that `AdDuplex.AdDuplexClient.Initialize("application-id-here");` code at App.xaml.cs.. I mean, put it at maybe MainPage.xaml.cs ?

Comment: @rydev I already tried that. It is an interstitial ad in a game, so its called programmatically. I doesn't matter where I put, it still causes the debugger to break.

Comment: have you tried the try block?

`try { AdDuplex.AdDuplexClient.Initialize("app-id"); } catch (Exception e) { Debug.WriteLine(e.Message); }` and see what the Debugger tells you :D

Comment: @rydev I have tried that. Like I said, it does not break on the *function call itself* but after that function is finished.

Comment: It seems that you are doing things correctly. Please contact AdDuplex via support@adduplex.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was never able to resolve this issue, but I reformatted my computer recently and was able to successfully incorporate AdDuplex into my app. It was obviously a problem with my development environment and reinstalling all the components solved the problem.